# How to sort array of objects?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sort an array of javascript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/how-to-sort-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

i have a array of objects:

```
var arr = []
arr[0] = new Object()
...
arr[n] = new Object()
```

I want to get sorted array by arr[i].getSortOrder() for example, where arr[i].getSortOrder() return integer value.  How to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the record:

```
arr.sort(function(a, b){return a.getSortOrder() - b.getSortOrder();});
```

For details see [Sorting an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/how-to-sort-an-array-of-javascript-objects) and the [MDN docs for the `sort()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).